# csv writer in python adding double quote when copying data from another csv file, So I just need to know how to copy exactly the same data

Tags: python, csv, parsing, quoting

```
#Reading from csv file
with open('py_csv/oscar_age_male.csv','r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file)

    #Creating new file and opening it and changing delimiter
    with open('py_csv/newfile.csv','w')as newfile:
        csv_writer=csv.writer(newfile)

#Writing Row by row
        for line in csv_reader:
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

**Data from originals file=**

```
1, 1928, 44, "Emil Janning", "The Last Command, The Way of All Flesh"
2, 1929, 41, "Warner Baxter", "In Old Arizona"
```

**Data after being copied=**

```
1, 1928, 44," ""Emil Janning"""," ""The Last Command"," The Way of All Flesh"""
2, 1929, 41," ""Warner Baxter"""," ""In Old Arizona"""
```

Comment: Just like the commas and the linebreaks, the quotes are part of the formatting. What is the actual verbatim content of the first file? What are the active settings for reading and writing concerning quoting? BTW: It's possible to represent the same data in different ways, like 0.5=1/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the spaces after the commas. Quotes are allowed around a field in a CSV, but since the field starts with a space, the quotes don't appear to be surrounding the whole field value. So they're being treated as literal quotes that need to be doubled in the output.

Use the `skipinitialspace` option to ignore those spaces.

```
csv_reader=csv.reader(csv_file, skipinitialspace=True)
```